# WP_Query() - meta_query OR tax_query

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to use `WP_Query` to create a query with both a `meta_query` element and `tax_query` element. The kicker is that I don't want to find the results where both conditions are met (and AND clause) I want to find the conditions where either one or the other are met (OR clause).

So I'm starting with these args:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'some-meta',
            'value' => 'some-value',
        )
    ),

    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'some-taxonomy',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array('some-term')
        )
    )
);
```

When run through `WP_Query` I get this where clause (simplified here for the sake of clarity):

```
WHERE ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (336) ) 
    AND ( 
        (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'some-meta' 
        AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'some-value') 
    )
```

Is it possible to pass some argument into the `WP_Query` object that will change that first AND to an OR? What I want is this:

```
WHERE ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (336) ) 
    OR ( 
        (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'some-meta' 
        AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'some-value') 
    )
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wordpress WP\_Query where clause with OR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630592/wordpress-wp-query-where-clause-with-or)

Comment: Derek - I don't think so (but I'm happy to be proved wrong). The link you shared shows ORs between multiple meta fields and I'm looking for an OR between a meta field and a tax field. I went ahead and tried their solution (for completion's sake) with no result.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, it appears that only changes the relation between meta (or tax) fields exclusively.

Comment: This is not possible using the WP_Query. You need to run a custom query for that.

Comment: If you post that as an answer I'll accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't achieve this with WP_Query. You've need to do a custom query for this.

Comment: I don't remember what I did (4 years ago) but I think I came to that conclusion. I am not (and was never really) a WP developer :)