# WordPress "s" query with a few keywords in $args

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have this query that works fine:

```
 $query = new WP_Query(array( 's' => $keyword ,'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'draft')) );
```

Its searches and finds the post with the keyword in title.

I want to query posts with a few keywords at once, (Now i'm doing a loop over all keywords and query each keyword by itself.

If it was mysql it would have be something like:

```
Select * from ..... where title='keyword1' or title='keyword2' or title='keyword3' ;
```

How could achieve that with WP_Query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress WP\_Query where clause with OR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630592/wordpress-wp-query-where-clause-with-or)

Comment: `meta_query` supports multiple clauses, title not.

Comment: If it was mysql, surely it would be something like `title IN('keyword1','keyword2',etc)`

Comment: I don't know this codex, but can't you do something like `$query = new WP_Query( array( 'title' => 'keyword1,keyword2,keyword3' ) );`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it using the `WP_Query` directly.

An alternative for looping the `WP_Query` is use the `$wpdb`.

```
$wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE where title='keyword1' or title='keyword2' or title='keyword3'" );
```

Answer (score 1):

U have to use $wpdb ([@codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb))

```
$query= $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( 
    "SELECT * FROM ....
        WHERE title= %s OR
        title=%s OR
        title = %s
    ", 
    $keyword1,
    $keyword2,
    $keyword3
) );
```

I hope that help u:)